# How is a 16 byte data type stored on a 64 bit machine

Tags: c++, c, memory-management

I have been seeing that we could use extended data types like unsigned long long which consume 16 bytes of memory, i.e. sizeof(an unsigned long long variable) results in 16 on my 64 bit machine, I understand that largest possible data type is restricted by the architecture of the system, i.e. to 8 bytes on my 64 bit machine, I just wanted to know how is this data type handled on a machine whose CPU instruction set is only 64 bit long. Please help.
Thanks

Comment: The same way a 64-bit `unsigned long long`  is handled on a 32-bit processor.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you meant ?

Comment: `largest possible data type is restricted by the architecture of the system` That isn't true.

Comment: Not to mention that the bus size of the CPU only limits the largest chunk it can handle in a single operation. `long long` (signedness is of no importance) variables can be processed an an 8-bit Z80 as well. A good example are BigNum libraries, able to handle numbers with way more bytes than 16.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler breaks it up into two 64-bit variables adjacent to each other, and uses the carry flag to make sure that they are treated as one big number when doing arithmetic.

Comment: Or simply use native 128-bit operations when available.