# What is a 16 byte signed integer data type?"

Tags: c++, c, types, integer

I made this program to test what data types arbitrary integer literals get evaluated to. This program was inspired from reading some other questions on StackOverflow.

[How do I define a constant equal to -2147483648?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612996/how-do-i-define-a-constant-equal-to-2147483648)

[Why do we define INT_MIN as -INT_MAX - 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003893/why-do-we-define-int-min-as-int-max-1)

[(-2147483648> 0) returns true in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695118/2147483648-0-returns-true-in-c)

In these questions, we have an issue: the programmer wants to write INT_MIN as `-`*2^31*, but *2^31* is actually a literal and `-` is the unary negation operator. Since INT_MAX is usually *2^31 - 1* having a 32-bit int, the literal *2^31* cannot be represented as an `int`, and so it gets promoted to a larger data type. The second answer in the third question has a chart according to which the data type of the integer literals is determined. The compiler goes down the list from the top until it finds a data type which can fit the literal.

> `Suffix       Decimal constants
>   none         int
>                long int
>                long long int`

=========================================================================

In my little program, I define a macro that will return the "name" of a variable, literal, or expression, as a C-string. Basically, it returns the text that is passed inside of the macro, exactly as you see it in the code editor. I use this for printing the literal expression.

I want to determine the data type of the expression, what it evaluates to. I have to be a little clever about how I do this. How can we determine the data type of a variable or an expression in C? I've concluded that only two "bits" of information are necessary: the width of the data type in bytes, and the signedness of the data type.

I use the `sizeof()` operator to determine the width of the data type in bytes. I also use another macro to determine if the data type is signed or not. `typeof()` is a GNU compiler extension that returns the **data type** of a variable or expression. But I cannot **read** the data type. I typecast `-1` to whatever that data type is. If it's a signed data type, it will still be `-1`, if it's an unsigned data type, it will become the `UINT_MAX` for that data type.

```
#include <stdio.h>   /* C standard input/output - for printf()     */
#include <stdlib.h>  /* C standard library      - for EXIT_SUCCESS */

/**
 * Returns the name of the variable or expression passed in as a string.
 */
#define NAME(x) #x

/**
 * Returns 1 if the passed in expression is a signed type.
 * -1 is cast to the type of the expression.
 * If it is signed, -1 < 0 == 1 (TRUE)
 * If it is unsigned, UMax < 0 == 0 (FALSE)
 */
#define IS_SIGNED_TYPE(x) ((typeof(x))-1 < 0)

int main(void)
{

    /* What data type is the literal -9223372036854775808? */

    printf("The literal is %s\n", NAME(-9223372036854775808));
    printf("The literal takes up %u bytes\n", sizeof(-9223372036854775808));
    if (IS_SIGNED_TYPE(-9223372036854775808))
        printf("The literal is of a signed type.\n");
    else
        printf("The literal is of an unsigned type.\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

As you can see, I'm testing `-`*2^63* to see what data type it is. The problem is that in ISO C90, the "largest" data type for integer literals appears to be `long long int`, if we can believe the chart. As we all know, `long long int` has a numerical range *-2^63* to *2^63 - 1* on a modern 64-bit system. However, the `-` above is the unary negation operator, not really part of the integer literal. I'm attempting to determine the data type of *2^63*, which is too big for the `long long int`. I'm attempting to cause a bug in C's type system. That is intentional, and only for educational purposes.

I am compiling and running the program. I use `-std=gnu99` instead of `-std=c99` because I am using `typeof()`, a GNU compiler extension, not actually part of the ISO C99 standard. I get the following output:

```
$ gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -pedantic experiment.c
$
$ ./a.out
The literal is -9223372036854775808
The literal takes up 16 bytes
The literal is of a signed type.
```

I see that the integer literal equivalent to *2^63* evaluates to a 16 byte signed integer type! As far as I know, there is no such data type in the C programming language. I also don't know of any Intel x86_64 processor that has a 16 byte register to store such an rvalue. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Explain what's going on here? Why is there no overflow? Also, is it possible to define a 16 byte data type in C? How would you do it?

Comment: Width and signedness aren't enough to identify a type, even an integer type. For example, `long` is almost always the same size as either `int` or `long long`.

Comment: Well, clearly neither `long` nor `long long` are 16 bytes! What do you suggest in order to identify an integer data type?

Comment: I believe some versions of gcc implement a 128-bit type, although it's typically "emulated in software", since you're right, most CPUs don't have registers and ALU's operating on such a size.

Comment: If you want to make decisions based on the type of an expression, [`_Generic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic) would be the standard way to go.

Comment: to print the result of `sizeof`, you should use `%zu`

Comment: "Well, clearly neither long nor long long are 16 bytes!" this statement requires additional qualifiers. C++ only specifies the **minimum** size of the fundamental integer types and leaves the upper end restricted only by the size of the next type up (`int` cannot be larger than `long`). It is entirely possible to have a system where all integers `char` through `long long` are 128 bits wide. Or 4096 bits, for that matter.

Comment: Yes, that kind of data types arrangement would indeed conform to the standard! Actually, I meant that on my 64-bit computer both, `long` and `long long` are 8 bytes wide.

Comment: Also there are no negative literals. The expression `-3` is unary minus operator applied to the literal `3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging this is what I've found. I converted the code to C++, assuming that C and C++ behave similarly in this case. I want to create a template function to be able to accept any data type. I use `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` which is a GNU compiler extension which returns a C-string containing the "prototype" of the function, I mean the return type, the name, and the formal parameters that are input. I am interested in the formal parameters. Using this technique, I am able to determine the data type of the expression that gets passed in exactly, without guessing!

```
/**
 * This is a templated function.
 * It accepts a value "object" of any data type, which is labeled as "T".
 *
 * The __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ is a GNU compiler extension which is actually
 * a C-string that evaluates to the "pretty" name of a function,
 * means including the function's return type and the types of its
 * formal parameters.
 *
 * I'm using __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ to determine the data type of the passed
 * in expression to the function, during the runtime!
 */
template<typename T>
void foo(T value)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

foo(5);
foo(-9223372036854775808);
```

Compiling and running, I get this output:

```
$ g++ -m64 -std=c++11 experiment2.cpp
$
$ ./a.out
void foo(T) [with T = int]
void foo(T) [with T = __int128]
```

I see that the passed in expression is of type `__int128`. Apparently, this is a GNU compiler specific extension, not part of the C standard.

[Why isn't there int128_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29638723/why-isnt-there-int128-t)

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.4/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.4/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions

[How is a 16 byte data type stored on a 64 bit machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25109065/how-is-a-16-byte-data-type-stored-on-a-64-bit-machine)

Comment: For C++,  Scott Mayers has recommended printing types with a compiler error on an declared but undefined template `template<class T> class TP; TP<decltype(LITERAL)> tp;`. My answer's basically using a `_Generic`-based C version of that strategy. (Anyway, you might not want to answer C-tagged questions with C++ code. Everybody knows us C programmers often HATE C++ :D ).

Comment: @PSkocik No problem, added the `c++` tag! Anyway, I tend to use C++ features interchangeably with C features. If I want to use something that C++ has that C lacks, I just do `#ifdef __cplusplus` and put that straight into the `.c` source code file, or I use an `extern "C"` to link C and C++ code together. Well, just use the tools that are available in your hands.

Comment: For me it's just like using any GNU compiler extensions or inline assembly code in C. So yes, it's not pure C.

Comment: Whereas `C++` is a programming language, `++C` is `C` code with c++ code and various non-standard extensions mixed in! :D

Answer (score 4):

Your platform likely has `__int128` and `9223372036854775808` is acquiring that type.

A simple way to get a C compiler to print a typename is with something like:

```
int main(void)
{

    #define LITERAL (-9223372036854775808)
    _Generic(LITERAL, struct {char x;}/*can't ever match*/: "");

}
```

On my x86_64 Linux, the above is generating an 
`error: ‘_Generic’ selector of type ‘__int128’ is not compatible with any association` error message, implying `__int128` is indeed the type of the literal.

(With this, the `warning: integer constant is so large that it is unsigned` is wrong. Well, gcc isn't perfect.)

Comment: @M.M Because the type is evidently signed.

Comment: @M.M O.P's question even includes a signedness test showing that the resulting type is signed.

Answer (score 3):

With all warnings enabled -Wall gcc will issue `warning: integer constant is so large that it is unsigned` warning. Gcc assigns this integer constant the type `__int128` and `sizeof(__int128) = 16`.
You can check that with _Generic macro:

```
#define typestring(v) _Generic((v), \
    long long: "long long", \
    unsigned long long: "unsigned long long", \
    __int128: "__int128" \
    )

int main()
{
    printf("Type is %s\n", typestring(-9223372036854775808));
    return 0;
}
```

```
Type is __int128
```

Or with warnings from printf:

```
int main() {
    printf("%s", -9223372036854775808);
    return 0;
}
```

will compile with warning:

```
warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type '__int128' [-Wformat=]
```

Comment: Clever way to find out the data type of a passed in expression or literal!

Comment: There's no cast involved. I think you mean to say that gcc uses the type of `__int128` for this constant.

Comment: Right, it just has the `__int128` type.